# GPO Create and Add a Mapped Drive custom to the username

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, login, mappeddrive

How can I create a Mapped Drive that is based on the Username of the user who is logging in?

In other words, if I specify the path `\\dc1\share\%username%` and have the user's computer log in every time and map to that, how can I have it create the folder, then use it as an H: drive every time they log in?

I don't want it to replace their personal folders, but I do just want it to be an optional drive they can use to store folders.

I have searched, and searched, and found nothing that works.

Comment: Have you considered a logon script to create the folder then map the drive?

Answer (score 0):

I have to create the folder first...